# How to find tweet density of a given twitter handle?

Tags: java, twitter

By tweet density, I mean the number of tweets, re-tweets and replies that user has tweeted in a given time frame.

The output can be in html or Json and the input can be a simple web service.

Are there any Java APIs that can help me do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) Java library for the Twitter API.
This can give you all details about the user tweets, retweets , and replies.

But before using this , you need to have token key/secret , consumer key/secret.
You can get this from this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/)

Comment: Hi, I am new to using twitter api, I did not understand what a key/secret is ? Can you explain or link to the exact page that has this ?

Comment: visit link https://dev.twitter.com and then enter your twitter account and password. and then click on create App.